# Hmisc - cut2 - create factors from times

Tags: r, hmisc

I'm trying to use the [`cut2()`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/Hmisc/docs/cut2) function from the [`Hmisc` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) to create a factor based on time periods.

Here's some code:

```
library(Hmisc)

i.time <- as.POSIXct("2013-07-16 13:55:14 CEST")
f.time <- i.time+as.difftime(1, units="hours")

data.points <- seq(from=i.time, to=f.time, by="1 sec")
cut.points <- seq(from=i.time, to=f.time, by="60 sec")



intervals <- cut2(x=data.points, cuts=cut.points, minmax=TRUE)
```

I expected intervals to be created such that each point in data.point were placed in a interval of time.
But there are some NA values in the end:

```
> tail(intervals, 1)
[1] <NA>
60 Levels: [2013-07-16 13:55:14,2013-07-16 13:56:14) ... [2013-07-16 14:54:14,2013-07-16 14:55:14]
```

I was expecting that the option `minmax=TRUE` would make sure that hte cuts included all the values in `data.points`.

Can anyone clarify what's going on here? How can I use the cut2 function to generate a factor that includes all the values in the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason I use `cut2` in preference to `cut` is that its default for "right" is the way I expect it to work (left-closed intervals). Looking at the code I see that when 'cuts' is present in the argument list, then the `cut` function is used with a shifted set of cuts that has the effect of making the intervals left-closed, and then the code relabels the factor to change the `"("`'s to `["`'s, but then does not use `include.lowest = TRUE`. This has the effect of turning the last value into `<NA>`. <s>Frankly, I see this as a bug.</s> After looking at this more closely I see that `cut2`'s help page does not promise to handle either `Date` or `date-time` objects, so "bug" is too strong. It completely fails with Date objects and it appears to be only an accident that is is almost correct with POSIXct objects. (This implementation is somewhat surprising to me in that I always assumed that it was just using `cut( ... , right=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE)`.)

You can alter the code and one idea I had was to extend the range back to the right end point in the original data by changing this line:

```
r <- range(x,  na.rm = TRUE)
```

To this line:

```
r <- range(c(x,max(x)+min(diff(x.unique))/2),  na.rm = TRUE)
```

It's not exactly the result I expected since you get a new category at the right end because the penultimate interval was still open on the right.

```
intervals <- cut3(x=data.points, cuts=cut.points, minmax=TRUE)
> tail(intervals, 1)
[1] 2013-07-16 14:55:14
61 Levels: [2013-07-16 13:55:14,2013-07-16 13:56:14) ...
> tail(intervals, 2)
[1] [2013-07-16 14:54:14,2013-07-16 14:55:14) 2013-07-16 14:55:14                      
61 Levels: [2013-07-16 13:55:14,2013-07-16 13:56:14) ...
```

A different idea gives a more satisfactory result. Change only this line:

```
y <- cut(x, k2)
```

To to this:

```
y <- cut(x, k2, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Giving the expected right and left closed interval and no NA:

```
 tail(intervals, 2)
[1] [2013-07-16 14:54:14,2013-07-16 14:55:14] [2013-07-16 14:54:14,2013-07-16 14:55:14]
60 Levels: [2013-07-16 13:55:14,2013-07-16 13:56:14) ...
```

Note: `include.lowest`=TRUE with right=FALSE, will actually become `include.highest`. And I'm scratching my head about why I am actually getting the desired behavior in this case when I did not also need to do something with the 'right' parameter. I sent Frank Harrell a message, and he is willing to consider revisions to the code to handle other cases. I'm working on that.

Why this is an issue: The labeling for `cut.POSIXt` and `cut.Date`  differs from the labeling of `cut.numeric` (actually `cut.default`) results. The former two label strategy is to just reprot the beginnings of the intervals whereas the labeling from `cut.numeric` includes "[" and ")" and the ends of the intervals. Compare the output from these:

```
levels( cut(0+1:100, 3) )
levels( cut(Sys.time()+1:100, 3) )
levels( cut(Sys.Date()+1:100, 3) )
```

Comment: +1! nice going in depth! just a question `cut2` use `cut`?  So internally you use `cut(x, k2, include.lowest=TRUE)`?

Comment: `cut2` does use `cut` and if you modify it to use include.lowest=TRUE, you get rid of the problem of date-time values coming back  with NA's. But that doesn't solve the problem for Date values (since they _all_ come back NA) and I'm still trying figure out the problem there.

Answer (score 1):

from `??cut2`:

> minmax : 
>   if cuts is specified but min(x) < min(cuts) or max(x) > max(cuts),
>   augments cuts to include min and max x

Checking your arguments:

```
x=data.points
cuts=cut.points
r <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE)
 (r[1] < min(cuts) | (r[2] > max(cuts)))
FALSE ## no need to include mean and max
```

So here setting `minmax` don't change the result. But here a result using `cut` by setting `include.lowest=TRUE)` :

```
res <- cut(x=data.points, breaks=cut.points, include.lowest=TRUE)
table(is.na(res))
```